# The set of fixed points of a Borel function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a Borel function, is the set $\{x : f(x)=x\}$ Borel?

Edit: As short questions seem to be quite unpopular here, I'll elaborate a little: As the graph of the function is Borel, the set $\{(x,f(x)) : f(x)=x\}$ is Borel, hence the set of fixed points of $f$ is analytic. Showing that it's Borel seems to be trickier.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Why did it get downvoted?

Comment: @DylanSp As the graph of $f$ is Borel, the set $\{(x,f(x)) : x=f(x)\}$ is Borel, but now it only follows that the set of fixed points of $f$ is analytic, I don't know how to show that it's Borel.

Comment: Add that to your question. I downvoted because right now, this is just a question dump with no effort shown.

Comment: Can you use the fact that Borel functions are a vector space containing continuous functions?

Comment: @Acuriousset: think about the function $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$.

Comment: If $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a Borel function, then $\{x : f(x)=x\}\;$ is a Borel set.

**Proof:**

Let $I: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$  be defined as $I(x)=x$. It is immediate that $I$ is a Borel function and so $f-I$ is a Borel function. So we have that $\{x : (f-I)(x)=0\}$ is a Borel set. Since 
$$ \{x : f(x)=x\}= \{x : f(x)-x=0\}=\{x : (f-I)(x)=0\}$$
we have that $\{x : f(x)=x\}$ is a Borel set.